# How to get jQuery to wait until after AngularJS has rendered an input element to set focus on it?

Tags: angularjs

I have an input element being created in an AngularJS directive:

```
<span ng-repeat="phrasePart in phraseParts">
    {{phrasePart}}<input ng-attr-id="{{ 'phrasePart-' + $index }}" ng-if="!$last"/>
</span>
```

and I want the first input element i.e. (`<input id="phrasePart-0" />` to receive focus, so I do this with jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $("#phrasePart-0").focus();
});
```

However, this code does set focus in an input element that is directly in the HTML and not rendered by AngularJS.

- How can I get jQuery to wait until the input element "phrasePart-0" is created by AngularJS before setting focus?
- Is there an "AngularJS way" to set focus that would be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more 'Angular' way to do it would to use a directive.

<s>then apply that directive to the first occurance as a class</s>

Just checked this. This is not the case because ng-class does not recompile dom elements for angular directives.

Instead, this may be a more reliable solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/9958/

```
.directive("focusme", function(){
  return {
      scope:{
          focusme:"="
      },
    link:function(scope, element, attrs, $timeout){
        if (scope.focusme){
            element[0].focus();
        }
    }
  }
})
```

and for the HTML

```
 <span ng-repeat="phrasePart in phraseParts">
        {{phrasePart}}<input ng-attr-id="{{ 'phrasePart-' + $index }}" ng-if="!$last" focusme="$first" />
    </span>
```

Comment: Ammended. ng-class does not call $compile which means the 'directive' class won't do anything.

Comment: I also like this approach more than using $timeout. It also seems to work using HTML5 autofocus attribute, changing 'element[0].focus();' to 'element[0].autofocus = true;', which is cool. Still, the fiddle doesn't work under Firefox for me :/

Answer (score 2):

Use, $timeout

Check out this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cndhpqrz/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function myfunc($scope, $timeout)
{

$scope.phraseParts=[1,2,3,4,5,6];

$timeout(function()
         {
    $("#phrasePart-2").focus();
});
}
```

Comment: Interesting, both your fiddle and my code don't work in Firefox, but work in Chrome.

Comment: They both work in IE11 as well. Do they work in your Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

use $timeout service of angularjs.

$timeout handler will be called after the digest cycle completes. So at that time you will have your input rendered.

```
$timeout(function () {
    $("#phrasePart-0").focus();
});
```